# Known problems with filemtime() on Windows - files getting touched arbitrarily?

Tags: php, windows, apache, caching, filemtime

Is there a known issue leading to file modification times of cache files on Windows XP SP 3 getting arbitrarily updated, but without any actual change?

Is there some service on a standard Windows XP - Backup, Sync, Versioning, Virus scanner - known to touch files? They all have a `.txt` extension.

If there isn't, forget it. Then I'm getting something wrong in my cache routines, and I'll debug my way through.

**Background:**

I'm building a simple caching wrapper around a slow web site on a Windows server.

I am comparing the `filemtime()` time stamp to some columns in the data base to determine whether a cached file is stale.

I'm having problems using this method because the modification time of the cache files seems to get updated in between operations *without me doing anything*. THis results in stale files being displayed.

I'm the only user on the machine. The operating system is Windows XP, the webserver a XAMPP Apache 2 with PHP 5.2

Comment: i have not experienced any such behaviour

Comment: Its Really a Surprise Finding Potter In Trouble... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup [logging](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/dotnet/file_system_monitoring.html)<sup>*</sup> on the machine to find out what is changing your files. From your description I take this happens frequently, so you might find [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) ([german](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)) to be a better solution for monitoring.

<sup>`*` I think you can setup logging with on-board tools as well, just not sure anymore how</sup>

Comment: The issue sorted itself somehow; marking this accepted for being a good general debugging approach.

Answer (score 1):

The only mtime issue I can think of is the dreaded [DST bug](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/datetime/dstbugs.aspx). It doesn't sound quite like what you're getting though.

Certainly there are other Windows tools that might modify a file behind your back, but typically it's user-level stuff like WMP screwing with the ID3 tags, or dodgy AV... not anything I would expect to be touching your cache files.

(Maybe you could try an equality comparison of mtimes rather than greater-than/less-than, only using the cache if there is an exact match? This at least means that if some anti-social bleeder is touching files it'll just slow you down a bit, instead of making you serve stale files. FWIW this is what Python does with its bytecode cache.)

Comment: Cheers Bobince, an equality comparison is a great idea. I'll do some more debugging and if my caching system is 100% innocent (as I said, not sure yet), I'll employ that.